# Rails AJAX remote: true with dynamic id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I implemented a basic AJAX Call in Rails, which is working fine with this:

**index.html.erb**

```
<a href="/days/new" data-remote="true" id="new_day_ajax">Add This day</a>
```

**new.js.erb**

```
$('#new_day_ajax').hide().after('<%= j render("form")%>');
```

The problem is I generate up to 31 a-tags like the above one on a single page with the following loop and the form will of course always show up at the first one, no matter which link I click:

```
end_date.downto(start_date).each do |date|
    [...]
```

To make the form show up at the clicked link I tried to generate the ids dynamically like so:

```
id="new_day_ajax_<%= date.strftime('%d') %>" <!-- i.e. new_day_ajax_07 -->
```

but now I don't know how to pass this dynamic id into the new.js.erb. How can I know the dynamic id inside of the javascript?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass GET parameter and get it from `params` object in `.erb` view

**index.html.erb**

```
<a href="/days/new?date=<%= date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') %>" 
    data-remote="true"
    id="new_day_ajax_<%= date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') %>">Add This day</a>
```

e.g.:

```
<a href="/days/new?date=2016-10-08" 
    data-remote="true"
    id="new_day_ajax_2016-10-08">Add This day</a>
```

**new.js.erb**

```
$('#new_day_ajax_<%= params[:date] %>').hide().after('<%= j render("form")%>');
```